# Self promotion in submissions?

Tags: discussion

The self promotion problem. It has been solved in the chat (making a boundary between irritating self promotion and honest hope), but have we gotten to consensus about submissions?

I've posted a [submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/190995/revisions) to challenge with a link to the answer's github repository (named, I have to agree, pretty suggestively "star me on github"). It was removed by one of the mods, quoting,

> removing self-promotion

Is this kind self promotion in submissions forbidden? I'm striving to find a rule for this, but it seems like there is none. Is this even a self-promotion?

Answer (score 6):

The rules you are looking for are in the Help Center: [How to not be a spammer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).

Specifically, that page states:

> **Don't include links except to support what you've written.** Links are not a substitute for including information in your answer itself, and links should always be directly relevant to a part of your answer.

Including a link to a GitHub repository where you have hosted the code and asking for stars is not directly relevant to the answer itself, and is solely self-promotion, which is not acceptable by the network-wide rules.

Comment: "Star me on github" is quite common saying, clicking the link doesn't necessairly make the user star the repo. The link to github contained some interesting and probably useful information like project files.

Comment: @KrzysztofSzewczyk Something being common isn't an argument for it being good. The same goes for being mandatory. Ads that play audio are common and don't force you to buy anything, but I still would rather they not exist.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman well, I hate them too. Shall we protest against audio ads?

Comment: To clarify, is the problem solely the request for stars? Would an answer that included the current state of the code plus a link to the version history be inappropriate?